# Mongoose Packs Each Object In An Array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

community!
I got some issue with mongoose. It adds an array of arrays to the database instead of an object array and packages each object into an array. What's going wrong?

So I create PaymentMethod, set `Array<IPayment>` to `fee`

```
export class PaymentMethod{
    @prop({ required: true, unique: true })
    public name: String

    @prop({ required: true })
    public details: String

    @prop({ required: true })
    public inlineMenu: String

    @prop({ required: true })
    public callbackData: String

    @prop({ required: true })
    public fee: Array<IPaymentFee>

    @prop({ default: false })
    public available: Boolean
}
```

`IPaymentFee` Interface:

```
export interface IPaymentFee {
    from: Number
    type: 'percent' | 'fixed'
    amount: Number
    extra?: Number | 0
}
```

Afterwards I create a new payment method:

```
const createdPayment = await PaymentMethodModel.create({
    name: 'xbank',
    details: '43284809328432',
    inlineMenu: 'menu_payment_xbank',
    callbackData: 'client_payment_xbank',
    available: true,
    fee: [
        { from: 0, type: 'fixed', amount: 200 },
        { from: 1000, type: 'percent', amount: 20, extra: 150 },
        { from: 1500, type: 'percent', amount: 17 },
        { from: 2000, type: 'percent', amount: 15 },
        { from: 3500, type: 'percent', amount: 13 },
        { from: 10000, type: 'percent', amount: 12 },
        { from: 20000, type: 'percent', amount: 11 },
        { from: 30000, type: 'percent', amount: 10 },
    ]}
)
```

But eventually I get incorrect result with an array of arrays instead of an array of objects --
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuN9C.jpg)

What am I doing wrong? Thx a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue, by adding method .lean() to all find/findOne methods